# How to have proper page numbers in docbook when converting from an xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, docbook

I am transforming a file from XML to doc book and generating a PDF after that. Can anyone suggest me how to have proper page numbers in the doc book when we create it. 
Now whatever i have created has:
No page numbers in the starting two pages but after two pages the third page is numbered as (iii) and then the forth page is numbered as 1 followed by 2,3,4 and so on. This is a problem for me when i want to search for a particular page in PDF. Ex: when i try to find page 4 it gives me something else as they are not numbered properly.

but what i want is :
page 1,2,3 and so on

can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you use the [docbook-xsl](/questions/tagged/docbook-xsl) stylesheets.

To get simple sequential numbering (1, 2, 3, ...) through the whole document, add the following to your customization layer:

```
<xsl:template name="page.number.format">1</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="initial.page.number">auto</xsl:template>
```

The default versions of these templates are found in pagesetup.xsl.

For more details, see http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintHeaders.html#PageNumbering.